# Installing Windows: error code 0x80070017

Tags: windows-7

I have been trying to install Windows 7 on my PC since last night but I keep getting this error code:

> Windows cannot install the required files. The file may be corrupt or
>   missing. Make sure   all files required for installation are available
>   and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070017

I searched Google for some answers and found [these](https://superuser.com/questions/33144/expanding-files-0-error-0x80070017-windows-7-x64-rtm).

I was able to finish the installation twice before. In those instances, the error code appeared, and I just restarted my PC and did things over again, each time doing a clean install.

Is it a faulty DVD or perhaps my optical drive? Or something else?

*The reason I keep reinstalling is because I can't get the Ubuntu dual-boot install right--GRUB issues. But that will go in a different thread.*

Comment: Check your RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try another DVD. It's happened to me before that I try an installation, it fails, and then use another DVD and that does the trick. That or maybe trying another optical drive, or even copy files to a thumb drive and use that.

Comment: You are right. This one DVD took half an hour to get to that part where it says it is expanding the files, then gives me an error message. Trying out a different dvd, everything was installed and up and running in ten minutes. @avirk-- I'll do that too. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not due to any error from the DVD or installation device.

This is happening only due to your hard disk having an error. Your hard disk likely contains bad sectors. You can fix it by using certain software (capable for repair during booting).

I have used Hiren's Boot CD. In this CD, it has a software namely DRevitaize v1.2. This program will fix bad sector errors in some cases. After fixing this error, your computer can install Windows 7 or any booting software without any additional work.

Answer (score 0):

If your system support to USB boot device then try with a USB to install the fresh copy. [Here](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) is the tool to make bootable USB disk software. And personally I will advise you to make an image of your windows DVD and use any virtual Dvd drive like Daemon, Alchohal or Magic ISO. Mount the image of your windows and make a bootable disk then try to install fresh setup of windows.

To Boot from USB go to your Bios setting and set the first boot device to USB and just boot from the USB once the updates installed by the windows setup and when restart the PC remove out your usb drive otherwise it will boot again through it.