# Windows 7 installation stuck on expanding Windows files (0%)

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expanding Files 0%, error 0x80070017 Windows 7 x64 RTM](https://superuser.com/questions/33144/expanding-files-0-error-0x80070017-windows-7-x64-rtm)

Windows 7 installation stuck on expanding Windows files (0%)

What are the causes? Is it common?  BTW, this is burned copy. I've installed Windows 7 previously using same DVD. But now it is stuck.

Error code: 0x80070017

Comment: This error is often caused by bad/corrupted install media.  Have you re-burned your image and tried installing again?

Comment: @jitendra789 - We will be unable to help you pirate Windows.

Comment: I edited it, the fact it's pirated doesn't really matter to the question or answers.  The fact it's a burned disk (pirated or not) may.

Comment: @jitendra789 So is your question "How do I get past this and get Windows installed", or is it really "Is this error common, and what causes it"?

Comment: @Ramhound No one said he was pirating, don't assume. You can legally download the ISOs.

Comment: @ekaj The OP themselves said they were pirating. Check the first revision of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your CD is corrupt in some way. Try reburning the CD, or using a program such as UNetBootin with the ISO.